# How to add space

Tags: python

How to add space to string.
example:
"Hiwatsup?"
or
"hi,hello"
return
"hi hello"
or
"hi"
"hello"

Comment: Maybe give us some sample code, with the output, and the output you'd like.

Comment: For "maybe", read "definitely". Nm3, you need to make this an actual question that's specific enough to have a definite answer.

Comment: Where do you want to add the spaces? What are the rules that should apply to this?

Answer (score 2):

For `"hi,hello"` you can just replace the "," for a whitespace:

```
hi = "hi,hello"
print hi.replace(",", " ")
```

you can also obtain a list of substrings split by a certain character:

```
print hi.split(',')
```

but what I **really** advise doing is looking at the documentation for str:

```
help(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
s = "hi,hello"
t = s.split(',')
print ' '.join(t)
```

And for the other one

```
>>> s = "Hiwatsup?"
>>> print s[:2] + ' ' + s[2:]
Hi watsup?
```

Instead of printing, you can assign it to another variable too.